# Is this concept of circle geometry known?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

Astonishingly, no mathematician ever could give a "Mr. Foobar invented this"
whenever I came up with this construction, although it is very elementary.

Given are 3 circles C1,C2,C3 (avoid degenerate configurations for now).
Let L be the geometric locus of the centers of all circles C which intersect
C1, C2 and C3 under the same angle @ (which may be non-real - doesn't hurt!)

Clearly the radical center (@=90°) and the all-outer/inner Apollonius center
(@=0/180°) lie on L, and some analytic geometry immediately shows L is a
straight line.

Bonus Track (only if you have too much time): Calculate @ for the 
Gergonne point when L is the Soddy line of C1, C2, C3. 
A most surprising result awaits. (Purely geometric proof, anyone?)

**Edit:** (Added from comments)

Here's an image:

[image]

The dotted circle is for @=120° (of course everything is drawn only approximate!)

Comment: Mathematicians are not responsible for memorizing the entire history of mathematics. I don't understand what you mean by $L$.

Comment: Welcome to the fray, Hauke!  It's an interesting idea, one new to me.

Comment: Here's an image: http://imgur.com/ttjN4 The dotted circle is for @=120° (of course everything is drawn only approximate!)

Comment: L is not a line but 4 lines, right? (E.g. when C1-C3 become straight lines L is 4 points: centers of in/ex-circles.)

Comment: @Grigory: If we specify a certain direction for directed angles, as I assumed in my solution, then there is one line for each of the 4 configurations. (Fix the direction of $C$ and $C_1$, then there are $2 \times 2$ configurations for $C_2$ and $C_3$.)

Comment: "This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what the Soddy line is, but I think I have solved the first part:

(I only consider the cases where $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ are pair-wise distinct)
Let the centre of $C$ be $O$ and the centres of $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ be $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$
If $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ have the same size,

  L is not a straight line but a point because the angle at the intersection of $C$ and $C_1$ is monotonic in $\overline{OO_1}$
  Thus $\overline{OO_1} = \overline{OO_2} = \overline{OO_3}$ and $O$ is unique

If $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ do not all have the same size,

  I think no two Apollonius circles can be concentric
  Thus there is a point at which inversion maps two corresponding ones to concentric circles
  In that case $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ map to circles of the same size, so we are back to the earlier case!
  $C$ must then map to a circle with centre $P$ uniquely defined by the images of $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$
  Thus the centre of $C$ must lie on the line uniquely defined by the inversion centre and $P$

(QED)

Comment: I forgot to mention that inversion preserves angles at intersections.